# Scroll of a texbox always on bottom

Tags: c#, winforms

There is a way to keep the scroll on bottom for a multi line textbox?

Something like in the vb6

```
txtfoo.selstart=len(txtfoo.text)
```

I'm trying with txtfoo.selectionstart=txtfoo.text.length without success.

Regards.

Comment: you have two solutions (yours and @monoxide's) that both seem to do what you want. I think you should accept one of them.

Comment: Except that you can't accept your own solution *shrugs* meh, I don't mind.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I automatically scroll to the bottom of a multiline text box?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/898307/10263).  (Actually this question is older, but the other has more answers and more votes.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I found that the solution was to use

```
txtfoo.AppendText
```

instead of

```
 txtfoo.text+="something"
```

Answer (score 4):

The other solution is to use:

```
txtfoo.Text += "something";
txtfoo.SelectionStart = txtfoo.Text.Length;
txtfoo.ScrollToCaret();
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I'm guessing that you are trying to select the text via form load? I can't get it working on form load, but I can on form click. Wierd. :)

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
        ScrollTextbox()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ScrollTextbox()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ScrollTextbox()
        TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.TextLength
        TextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
    End Sub

End Class
```

If it is completely necessary, you could use a timer.

Comment: I'd guess it has something to do with the form not being properly initialised yet in the load handler. Try putting a call to this.Show() first, should clear up any issues.