# How do I automatically scroll to the bottom of a multiline text box?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, scroll

I have a textbox with the .Multiline property set to true.  At regular intervals, I am adding new lines of text to it.  I would like the textbox to automatically scroll to the bottom-most entry (the newest one) whenever a new line is added.  How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Looked here for the answer, couldn't find it, so when I figured it out, I figured I'd put it up here for future users, or if maybe someone else had a better approach.

Comment: I needed to do the same thing in VBA, which doesn't have all these fancy-pants new .NET methods. For future google-fu, here is the incantation:  TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & "whatever"; TextBox1.SelStart = Len(TextBox1.Text); TextBox1.SetFocus;   ... and then a .SetFocus back to whatever control had the focus before. Without giving the focus to TextBox1, it would never update its scrollbars no matter what I did.

Comment: @GordonBroom Whelp, thanks to that I'm going to start calling "code snippets" "incantations" now. Good work. :D

Answer (score 519, accepted):

> At regular intervals, I am adding new lines of text to it. I would like the textbox to automatically scroll to the bottom-most entry (the newest one) whenever a new line is added.

If you use [`TextBox.AppendText(string text)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext.aspx), it will automatically scroll to the end of the newly appended text. It avoids the flickering scrollbar if you're calling it in a loop.

It also happens to be an order of magnitude faster than concatenating onto the `.Text` property. Though that might depend on how often you're calling it; I was testing with a tight loop.

---

This will not scroll if it is called before the textbox is shown, or if the textbox is otherwise not visible (e.g. in a different tab of a TabPanel). See [TextBox.AppendText() not autoscrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18260702/textbox-appendtext-not-autoscrolling). This may or may not be important, depending on if you require autoscroll when the user can't see the textbox.

It seems that the alternative method from the other answers also don't work in this case. One way around it is to perform additional scrolling on the `VisibleChanged` event:

```
textBox.VisibleChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (textBox.Visible)
    {
        textBox.SelectionStart = textBox.TextLength;
        textBox.ScrollToCaret();
    }
};
```

---

Internally, `AppendText` does something like this:

```
textBox.Select(textBox.TextLength + 1, 0);
textBox.SelectedText = textToAppend;
```

But there should be no reason to do it manually.

<sup>(If you decompile it yourself, you'll see that it uses some possibly more efficient internal methods, and has what seems to be a minor special case.)</sup>

Comment: Was eating myself trying to make it with `tb.Text += ....` and WndProc and marshals Now I feel stupid :D

Comment: still, for me (.NET 3.5) things only worked when I added the suggested code with SelectionStart & ScrollToCaret to TextChanged event handler (see below), because otherwise at some point (not always), the scroll would be reset to the beginning (probably the best solution would be to override that default code..)

Comment: @hello_earth I have updated with a workaround for the case where the textbox is not scrolling while invisible. You can try and see if that works for you.

Comment: The textarea also needs to be focused, the first time I did this it did not scroll because it did not have the focus.

Comment: i was setting the text in the Form's Load event. i was unable to get my `TextBox` to scroll to the bottom when i put `txtInfo.SelectionStart = txtInfo.Text.Length; txtInfo.ScrollToCaret(); txtInfo.Refresh();` in the Load event. i tried to put this code in the `TextBox`'s VisibleChanged event too, to no avail. what i did that worked was putting this code (`txtInfo.SelectionStart = txtInfo.Text.Length; txtInfo.ScrollToCaret();`) in a timer tick event & then start that timer at the end of the Load event. it worked even with 1 ms delay. not sure why it just didn't work for me in the Load event.

Comment: `textBox.VisibleChanged` not work.But I change that into txtResponse.TextChanged and it's work.

Comment: @Bob thanks for the tip. Works great! I would add that you might want to add Environment.Newline to each string added.

Comment: I had the issue where it would refuse to scroll to the end. I was loading in a log file at the start of my application. The solution was to put the code from above answer in the 'Shown' event (ie `MyForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)`).

Comment: AppendText did not automatically scroll my ReadOnly TextBox, but adding TextBox.ScrollToEnd(); after the AppendText call did the trick.

Answer (score 169):

You can use the following code snippet:

```
myTextBox.SelectionStart = myTextBox.Text.Length;
myTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
```

which will automatically scroll to the end.

Comment: Looked here for the answer, couldn't find it, so when I figured it out, I figured I'd put it up here for future users, or if maybe someone else had a better approach.

Comment: This may have been the best answer at the time, but now I think Bob's answer is a better solution to the OP's problem.

Answer (score 43):

It seems the interface has changed in [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) 4.0.  There is the following [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WINDOWS.CONTROLS.PRIMITIVES.TEXTBOXBASE.SCROLLTOEND%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) that achieves all of the above. As Tommy Engebretsen suggested, putting it in a TextChanged event handler makes it automatic.

```
textBox1.ScrollToEnd();
```

Comment: Note that that method is in the `TextBoxBase` class in the `System.Windows.Controls.Primitives` namespace (`PresentationFramework` assembly, WPF). This method does not exist and will not work in WinForms, whose `TextBox` class inherits from `TextBoxBase` in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace (`System.Windows.Forms` assembly, WinForms).

Comment: Note that `ScrollToEnd()` can be extremely poor performing.  In my app it accounted for over 50% of the profiling time.

Answer (score 18):

Try to add the suggested code to the TextChanged event:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
  textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
}
```

Answer (score 16):

```
textBox1.Focus()
textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
```

didn't work for me (Windows 8.1, whatever the reason).
And since I'm still on .NET 2.0, I can't use ScrollToEnd.

But this works:

```
public class Utils
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int SendMessage(System.IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam);

    private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;
    private const int SB_BOTTOM = 7;

    /// <summary>
    /// Scrolls the vertical scroll bar of a multi-line text box to the bottom.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tb">The text box to scroll</param>
    public static void ScrollToBottom(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox tb)
    {
        if(System.Environment.OSVersion.Platform != System.PlatformID.Unix)
             SendMessage(tb.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, new System.IntPtr(SB_BOTTOM), System.IntPtr.Zero);
    }


}
```

VB.NET:

```
Public Class Utils
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet := System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As System.IntPtr, wMsg As Integer, wParam As System.IntPtr, lParam As System.IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function

    Private Const WM_VSCROLL As Integer = &H115
    Private Const SB_BOTTOM As Integer = 7

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Scrolls the vertical scroll bar of a multi-line text box to the bottom.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="tb">The text box to scroll</param>
    Public Shared Sub ScrollToBottom(tb As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox)
        If System.Environment.OSVersion.Platform <> System.PlatformID.Unix Then
            SendMessage(tb.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, New System.IntPtr(SB_BOTTOM), System.IntPtr.Zero)
        End If
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Had the same issue with Windows 10, your workaround works fine here too.

Comment: Works for me (Windows 10) Thx

Comment: Other answers didn't work, this one did. Windows 10, 4.7.2.

Comment: Works for me on Win 11, nothing else did.

Answer (score 9):

I needed to add a refresh:

```
textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
textBox1.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 8):

I use this. Simple, clean and fast!

```
txtTCPTxRx.AppendText(newText);
```

Below is the actual code I use

```
ThreadSafe(() =>
      {
          string newLog = $"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss:ffff->}{dLog}{Environment.NewLine}";
          txtTCPTxRx.AppendText(newLog);
      });
```

Answer (score 6):

I found a simple difference that hasn't been addressed in this thread.

If you're doing all the `ScrollToCarat()` calls as part of your form's `Load()` event, it doesn't work.  I just added my `ScrollToCarat()` call to my form's `Activated()` event, and it works fine.

**Edit**

It's important to only do this scrolling the first time form's `Activated` event is fired (not on subsequent activations), or it will scroll **every** time your form is activated, which is something you probably don't want.

So if you're only trapping the `Activated()` event to scroll your text when your program loads, then you can just unsubscribe to the event inside the event handler itself, thusly:

```
Activated -= new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Activated);
```

If you have other things you need to do each time your form is activated, you can set a `bool` to true the first time your `Activated()` event is fired, so you don't scroll on subsequent activations, but can still do the other things you need to do.

Also, if your `TextBox` is on a tab that isn't the `SelectedTab`, `ScrollToCarat()` will have no effect.  So you need at least make it the selected tab while you're scrolling.  You can wrap the code in a `YourTab.SuspendLayout();` and `YourTab.ResumeLayout(false);` pair if your form flickers when you do this.

**End of edit**

Hope this helps!

Comment: You probably prefer to override the OnShown method: "protected override void OnShown (EventArgs e)" instead of putting an event handler for Activate.

Answer (score 4):

With regards to the comment by Pete about a TextBox on a tab, the way I got that to work was adding

```
textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
```

to the tab's Layout event.

Answer (score 1):

This will scroll to the end of the textbox when the text is changed, but still allows the user to scroll up

```
outbox.SelectionStart = outbox.Text.Length;
outbox.ScrollToEnd();
```

tested on Visual Studio Enterprise 2017

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else landing here expecting to see a webforms implementation, you want to use the Page Request Manager's endRequest event handler (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1388170/1830512). Here's what I did for my TextBox in a Content Page from a Master Page, please ignore the fact that I didn't use a variable for the control:

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

function EndRequestHandler() {
    if ($get('<%= ((TextBox)StatusWindow.FindControl("StatusTxtBox")).ClientID %>') != null) {
        $get('<%= ((TextBox)StatusWindow.FindControl("StatusTxtBox")).ClientID %>').scrollTop = 
        $get('<%= ((TextBox)StatusWindow.FindControl("StatusTxtBox")).ClientID %>').scrollHeight;
    }
}

prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
```

Answer (score -1):

This only worked for me...

txtSerialLogging->Text = "";

txtSerialLogging->AppendText(s);

I tried all the cases above, but the problem is in my case text s can decrease, increase and can also remain static for a long time.
static means , static length(lines) but content is different.

So, I was facing one line jumping situation at the end when the length(lines) remains same for some times...

Comment: I know, it is similar to Bob's answer, but explains a specific case. AND I can't comment on Bob's answer... Stuck with stackoverflow rules :(

Answer (score -1):

I use a function for this :

```
private void Log (string s) {
    TB1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + s);
    TB1.ScrollToCaret();
}
```