# how to scroll asp.net textbox to bottom

Tags: asp.net, ajax, textbox, scroll

I'm building a website with text box containing log messages. the log is getting updated using AJAX.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"                                 
            onload="textbox_load"
            Height="110px" 
            TextMode="MultiLine"             
            Width="100%">
        </asp:TextBox>    
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I need to scroll the text box down every time it gets updated. How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handle the [Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.endRequest](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/ClientReference/Sys.WebForms/PageRequestManagerClass/PageRequestManagerEndRequestEvent.aspx) event and scroll the textbox down:

```
var tbox = $get('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>');
tbox.tbox.scrollTop = tbox.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: .scrollDown() seems to be not defined! I'm getting a javascript exception

Comment: Im trying this but to now effect, where should the above script go exactly? I have it outside my html tags, inside beside my textbox and neither works, scroll bar remains at the top of the textbox after every refresh!

Comment: Worked for me. For testing, I didn't create the variable, but I'm using this code to scroll the TextBox control in a Content Page from a Master Page. Here is my working, rough implementation: `var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(); function EndRequestHandler() {if ($get('<%= (TextBox)StatusWindow.FindControl("StatusTxtBox")).ClientID %>') != null) {$get('<%= ((TextBox)StatusWindow.FindControl("StatusTxtBox")).ClientID %>').scrollTop = $get('<%= ((TextBox)StatusWindow.FindControl("StatusTxtBox")).ClientID %>').scrollHeight;}} prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);`

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try this simple example:

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

```
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
            "ScrollTextbox",
            "<script type=\"text/javascript\">document.getElementById('" +
            this.TextBox1.ClientID +
            "').scrollTop = document.getElementById('" +
            this.TextBox1.ClientID +
            "').scrollHeight; " +
            " </script>");
        }
    }
```

Just change TextBox1 parameter with your text box name. You can see that the content in the text box is scrolled to bottom.

You can call this java script after AJAX is refreshing the content of your text box.

Answer (score 0):

Try some plain javascript. Here's a sample I think you can modify to work in your scenario:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function scrollDown() 
    {
      document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').scrollTop = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').scrollHeight;
    };
  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

You just have to figure out how to call the scrollDown method...

Comment: this might be good for textarea HTML control, but how to add a javascript function to asp:TextBox server control?