# How to make autoscroll multiline TextBox in WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I automatically scroll to the bottom of a multiline text box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898307/how-do-i-automatically-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-multiline-text-box)

I use a multiline `TextBox` to output some information in new lines as it arrives from a `BackgroundWorker`.

Can I make it to scroll to the very bottom each time a new line arrives?

By default it seems to do just the opposite - it scrolls to the very first line each time a new line arrives and the `Text` property is changed.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Set the `TextBox` properties:

```
Multiline = True;
ScrollBars = Both;
```

To auto scroll on the `TextChanged` event:

```
textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
```