# Autoscroll to the bottom of a multiline textbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox, visual-studio-2015

I have started to make a master-server program for a small project involving rebuilding a game on a newer engine.
The master server program currently looks like this:

[image]

The large textbox with the 'Found 4 installed processor(s)' is a 'console' which outputs raw event messages sent to and from clients/gameservers using the master-server. It cannot be inputted into and the administrator (*the only person who has access to this interface of the master-server program*) can only copy from the textbox; they cannot delete/add anything.

The issue is that because it's supposed to be a 'console', it should automatically scroll down to the last line of the multiline textbox.

There are many questions on Stack Overflow which cover this ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728585/autoscroll-to-bottom-of-multiline-textbox-being-updated-by-backgroundworker) for example), but I haven't been able to get it working (the textbox doesn't scroll down) when placing the code within the `console_TextChanged` subroutine.
I have tried this:

```
Private Sub console_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles console.TextChanged
    console.AppendText(Text)
    console.Select(console.TextLength, 0)
    console.ScrollToCaret()
End Sub
```

It doesn't work, but it does however cause a bug in the program where each line is appended with the program's title quite a few times:

```
[net 11:32:22.243] System Started.Server Network | Crysis Wars 1.5Server Network | Crysis Wars 1.5Server Network | Crysis Wars 1.5Server Network | Crysis Wars 1.5Server Network | Crysis Wars 1.5Server Network | Crysis Wars 1.5Server Network | Crysis Wars 1.5Server Network | Crysis Wars 1.5Server Network | Crysis Wars 1.5Server Network | Crysis Wars 1.5
```

Some C# solutions have also worked for me in Visual Basic .Net in the past, and so I have tried [some of the ones on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505248/how-to-make-autoscroll-multiline-textbox-in-winforms) but I haven't been able to get these working either.

Is this really the correct way to autoscroll a multilined textbox, and if so, why is it not working for me?

***The complete (relevant) code:***

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    console.Text = GetNetTime() + "System Started."
    WriteToConsole("Working Area: " + CStr(My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea().Width) + "*" + CStr(My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea().Height))
    WriteToConsole("Found " + CStr(Environment.ProcessorCount) + " installed processor(s)")
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    While (i < Environment.ProcessorCount)
        WriteToConsole("Processor " + CStr(i) + ": " + My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\" + CStr(i)).GetValue("ProcessorNameString"))
        WriteToConsole("            Family: " + My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\" + CStr(i)).GetValue("Identifier"))
        WriteToConsole("            Manufacturer: " + My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\" + CStr(i)).GetValue("VendorIdentifier"))
        i += 1
    End While
    WriteToConsole("Starting networking services")
End Sub
Private Sub console_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles console.TextChanged
    console.AppendText(Text)
    console.Select(console.TextLength, 0)
    console.ScrollToCaret()
End Sub
Function GetNetTime()
    Return "[net " + CStr(DateTime.UtcNow.Hour) + ":" + CStr(DateTime.UtcNow.Minute) + ":" + CStr(DateTime.UtcNow.Second) + "." + CStr(DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond) + "] "
End Function
Function WriteToConsole(ByVal input As String)
    console.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & GetNetTime() + input)
    Return -1
End Function
```

Comment: What do you meant by doesn't work. You shouldn't call `AppendText` inside `TextChanged` event as it will result in non stop loop. `AppendText` will fire `TextChanged` adds another one `AppendText` which in turn fires `TextChanged` and so on. It will take forever.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel That'll explain why the program's title was appended so much to each line. Where/how can I do it properly? Edited to add that the textbox doesn't scroll when I use that code.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. If you simply use `AppendText` alone, that works(I mean scrolls properly). Post some short but complete sample which reproduces the problem.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Added the code, but then I still have the problem that the program title is appended at the end of every line a few times. How can I get over that hurdle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using `AppendText`, you can completely get rid of that `console_TextChanged` method because `AppendText` already does this for you.

For some reason (may be a bug?) when the `TextBox` is not exposed to the screen, `AppendText` doesn't seem to scroll to end. I have no good explanation now, need to look into the .Net framework source.

As a workaround just move all your code to `MyBase.Shown` event, not `Load` event. That works as expected, difference is `Shown` event will be raised as soon as the Form is first rendered in the screen as opposed to `Load` which gets fired before the form is rendered.

Answer (score 11):

One more useful solution:

```
textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length
textBox1.ScrollToCaret()
```

It just put cursor at the end of text in textbox and scroll to current cursor position. Worked for me perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in *load event* but it is more complicated:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function
```

After setting the text in `textbox`:

```
If (console.IsHandleCreated) Then
    'set focus
    SendMessage(console.Handle, &H7, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero) 'WM_SETFOCUS
    'move caret to the end
    SendMessage(console.Handle, &HB1, CType(-1, IntPtr), CType(-1, IntPtr)) 'EM_SETSEL
    'scroll to the end
    SendMessage(console.Handle, &HB6, IntPtr.Zero, CType(console.Lines.Length, IntPtr)) 'EM_LINESCROLL
Else
    MsgBox("console window is not created")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `RichTextBox` instead of a `TextBox` you can use this code.

```
'SENDMESSAGE constants
'move to the last row in a RichTextBox
'you can obtain the same effect using ScrollToCaret but it works only if Focus is on RichTextBox
Private Const WM_VSCROLL As Int32 = &H115
Private Const SB_BOTTOM As Int32 = 7

Private Sub WriteLog(ByVal strLineLog As String)

    If Me.rtbLog.Text = "" Then
        Me.rtbLog.Text = strLineLog
    Else
        Me.rtbLog.AppendText(System.Environment.NewLine & strLineLog)
    End If

    SendMessage(Me.rtbLog.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, SB_BOTTOM, 0)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
TextBox1.Select(TextBox1.TextLength - 1, 1) 'select the last chr in the textbox
TextBox1.ScrollToCaret() 'scroll to the selected position
```