# Press a key from keyboard keys automatically at run time on textbox when I use it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to make my program press "End" button (from keyboard) on textBox when I use it for writing .

As example this code is not correct :

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   e.KeyCode = Keys.End; //wrong !!
}
```

Thanks for all..

Comment: If you want to scroll the box to the end, search for ways [to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898307/how-do-i-automatically-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-multiline-text-box), rather than simulating a key press to do so in a roundabout way. Otherwise, there's also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047375/simulating-key-press-c-sharp) post to simulate a keypress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've suggested above will execute on every key up event, which I think would not be what you want, this would effectively stop a user from easily editing the text in the centre of the text box.

If you just want the cursor to start at the end of the text when the text box received focus, perhaps you chould hook into the `GotFocus` Event, and then use the `SendKeys.Send()` method to send the End key.

```
this.tGID.GotFocus += OnFocus;

private void OnFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SendKeys.Send("{END}");
}
```

Comment: It's work good , thanks .
I use just 
SendKeys.Send("{END}");

Comment: I'm glad, please don't forget to accept an answer if your issue is resolved.

Comment: yes it's resolved , but how can I accept it (i'm new here) ?

Comment: Looks like you've done it, thanks, and welcome to StackOverflow